# jQuery JTable to getRecordByKey

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-jtable

I'm using [jQuery jtable](http://jtable.org/). I know this is should be easy and simple but i can't get it work, from the [document](http://jtable.org/ApiReference/Methods#met-getRowByKey) 
the syntax should be like this , (Am i wrong?)

```
$('#myTable').jtable('getRowByKey', {key: 2})
```

and this is my jtable

```
$('#myTable').jtable({
    paging: false,
    sorting: false, 
    actions: {
    },
    fields: {
        intTest: {
            key: true,
            create: false,
            edit: false,
            list: false,
        },
        Name: {
            title: 'Name',
            width: '50%'
        }
    }
}).jtable('load');
```

But i always get null from above synxtax, Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Please show more code or even better add a jsfiddle.  There are many reasons why it couldn't be working but without more code we won't start guessing into the wild.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myTable').jtable({
                paging: false,
                sorting: false,
                actions: {
                    listAction: 'ControllerName?action=list',
                    createAction:'ControllerName?action=create',
                    updateAction: 'ControllerName?action=update',
                    deleteAction: 'ControllerName?action=delete'
                },
                fields: {
                    intTest: {
                        key: true,
                        create: false,
                        edit: false,
                        list: false,
                    },
                    Name: {
                        title: 'Name',
                        width: '50%'
                    }                
                }
            });   
            $('#myTable').jtable('load');
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var rowElement = $('#myTable').jtable('getRowByKey', 2);
```